# C# Как выделить кнопку?

Tags: c#, winforms, элементы-управления

Такой вопрос. Есть у меня на форме текстБокс. При событии входа в этот чекбокс нужно выделить/перейти к другому элементу. Например выделить кнопку. Не добавить ей обводку, не сменить цвет или что-то подобное что я находил в гугле. А именно выделить стандартным способом как если бы кнопкой Tab перешел к этой кнопке.
[image: Вот тут выделена кнопка "Нет"]

Или более сложный вариант. При входе в текстБокс, под ним у меня отображается чекедЛистБокс. И в этот момент выделение должно сместиться с текстБокса на чекедЛистБокс. Например так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как подобное осуществить?

Comment: _Ваш вопрос оформлен неверно, он содержит несколько вопросов. Нужно сфокусироваться на одной проблеме, то есть конкретизировать вопрос._ Отредактируйте его.

Comment: [MessageBoxDefaultButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messageboxdefaultbutton?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), [Control.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.select?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), [Control.Focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focus?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)